# Localization approach for XSLT + RESX in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, localization, resx

I have an ASP.NET web app where the back end data (XML format) is transformed using XSLT, producing XHTML which is output into the page.

Simplified code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = MyRepository.RetrieveXmlData(keyValue);
XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsl.Load(pathToXsl, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, null);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xsl.Transform(xmlDoc, null, stringWriter);
myLiteral.Text = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Currently my XSL file contains the XHTML markup elements, as well as text labels, which are currently in English. for example:

```
<p>Title:<br />
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</p>
<p>Description:<br />
  <xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
</p>
```

I would like the text labels (Title and Description above) to be localized. I was thinking of using .NET resource files (.resx), but I don't know how the resx string resources would get pulled in to the XSLT when the transformation takes place.

I would prefer not to have locale-specific copies of the XSLT file, since that means a lot of duplicate transformation logic.

(NOTE: the XML data is already localized, so I don't need to change that)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the text in the XSLT files with a placeholder element and then write another localizing transformation that takes the resx file and uses it to replace the placeholders with the desired piece of text.

```
<p><localized name="title"/>:<br />
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</p>
<p><localized name="desc"/>:<br />
  <xsl:value-of select="desc"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML document may contain either one language with one XML document for each language, or alternatively, a single XML document with all languages. The XML formats in the following example follows Microsoft .NET resource (.resx) files (one file per language) or a single TMX (translation memory exchange) document with all languages. Any format, however, may be used as long as the XPath used to read the text is consistent.

See my article "[How to localize XSLT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338731/LocalizeXSLT)" for a complete, functional sample at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338731/LocalizeXSLT.

Comment: This is not a practical solution. The resource file has to be distributed along with the solution if you do it this way.

Comment: The XML file(s) with the translated strings are distributed with the XSLT. The .resx format is a standard format. I don't see why this is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Since a .Resx file is an XML file you could use it as another source for the XSLT, by using the [document function](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp).